# Entity Framework Core pointing at multiple databases, depending on user?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am a Java programmer learning C# on the job and I have inherited a C# stand alone web application using Entity Framework Core to talk to a Microsoft SQL backend.

Now we need to be able to specify which database instance the user wants to use at runtime (based on a table lookup), and due to the way the code is build I essentially need to be able to replace

```
dbContext.TableName.Where(....)....
```

with

```
dbContext.ChooseDatabase(...).TableName.Where(....)....
```

everywhere in the client code.  The context is currently shared between all users, and there is not a session object in the client side of the code.

What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: You need to instantiate your DbContext class for each request based on the user.  This is multi-tenancy and the chosen database would be driven by a connection string for the specific tenant.  See ... https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-database-per-tenant/

Comment: @NeilW Thank you, both for the link and for introducing the vocabulary to me.  I have found that the previous owner of this project did not know that the context objects should be short lived.  Allowing a per-usage initialization of the context helps a lot.